# CSS resource opens as link (not importing) in jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp

Opening index page styles do not apply. When clicking on the link with css in the source code of index page in browser it shows up as new tab with the url like this: **`http://localhost:8080/resources/css/index.css`**
and showing the same index page without applied styles. Page is index.jsp. All other pages are working as they should.

I have the following code:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<link href="${root}/resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: That just means the URL you provided in the `href` resolves to the HTML document. We have no idea how your server is configured so its rather hard to say why that is.

Comment: Yes. When changing css to for example indexpage.css and changing link to <link href="${root}/resources/css/indexpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
everything works fine.